# loading dll from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service which runs fine locally but on the deployment machine I get this exception:

```
ERROR   Unable to load DLL 'c://XYX//Something.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

However, the dll is there. Not sure what the issue is. Any ideas?

Comment: your path doesn't look right. Should be `c:\\XYX\\Something.dll`

Comment: That comes from pinvoke  [DllImport(@"c://XYX//Something.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

Comment: You need to create a user on this machine with some permissions and then, once your service installed, go into properties and on Logon tab - set user account and password for service to use.

Comment: I am using Logon on as: Local System account

Comment: There is a trick about this. I forgot exactly... You need to create a user and logon as that user into your machine. Than you can use that user as "RunAs". Long time ago I used to have that issue...

Comment: I already tried to run the service as the user I am logged in. Is this not the same?

Comment: You know what... may be you have simple bitness issue. Try this. Compile your Dll, the whole service setup to x86 platform and lets see what happens.

Comment: They are already compiled as x86

Comment: Did you check using corFlags.exe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have 1 of 2 problems.

A permissions problem. -- Double check the security context that the service is running is appropriate and that it has the corresct permssions for that directory and file.

You are missing a requiired DLL. The Dependency Walker app is a convenient way to see what other DLL are statically linked with your DLL. If a statically linked DLL cannot be loaded, you will see this error.

Comment: I am using Logon on as: Local System account - I presume that's the account I remote remotely into the machine with. I have given this account all rights for the folder the dll lives in.

Comment: So, did you look for statically linked dll's

Comment: Use Dependency Walker -- it will show you any statically linked DLL's

Comment: I ended up using depends.exe which found that MSVCR100D.DLL was not installed on the target machine. Thanks!